# Fastest way to compute maximal n s.t. n over k <= x

Tags: c, algorithm, combinations

I'm looking for a fast way to compute the maximal `n` s.t. `n` over `k` <= `x` for given `k` and `x`.
In my context  `n \leq n'` for some known constant `n'`, lets say 1000. `k` is either 1,2, or 3 and `x` is choosen at random from `0 ... n' over k`

My current approach is to compute the binomial coefficient iterativly, starting from `a_0 = k over k = 1`. The next coefficient `a_1 = k+1 over k` can be computed as `a_1 = a_0 * (k+1) / 1` and so on.
The current C code looks like this

```
uint32_t max_bc(const uint32_t a, const uint32_t n, const uint32_t k) {
   uint32_t tmp = 1;
   int ctr = 0;
   uint32_t c = k, d = 1;
   while(tmp <= a && ctr < n) {
      c += 1;
      tmp = tmp*c/d;
      ctr += 1;
      d += 1;
   }

   return ctr + k - 1;
}

int main() {
   const uint32_t n = 10, w = 2;

   for (uint32_t a = 0; a < 10 /*bc(n, w)*/; a++) {
      const uint32_t b = max_bc(a, n, w);
      printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
   }
}
```

which outputs

```
0 1
1 2
2 2
3 3
4 3
5 3
6 4
7 4
8 4
9 4
```

So I'm looking for a Bittrick or something to get around the `while`-loop to speed up my application. Thats because the while loop gets executedat worst `n-k` times. Precomputation is not an option, because this code is part of a bigger algorithm which uses a lot of memory.

Thanks to @Aleksei
This is my solution:

```cpp
template<typename T, const uint32_t k>
inline T opt_max_bc(const T a, const uint32_t n) {
    if constexpr(k == 1) {
        return n - k - a;
    }

    if constexpr (k == 2) {
        const uint32_t t = __builtin_floor((double)(__builtin_sqrt(8 * a + 1) + 1)/2.);
        return n - t - 1;
    }

    if constexpr (k == 3) {
        if (a == 1)
            return n-k-1;

        float x = a;
        float t1 = sqrtf(729.f * x * x);
        float t2 = cbrtf(3.f * t1 + 81.f * x);
        float t3 = t2 / 2.09f;
        float ctr2 = t3;
        int ctr = int(ctr2);

        return  n - ctr - k;
    }

    if constexpr (k == 4) {
        const float x = a;
        const float t1 = __builtin_floorf(__builtin_sqrtf(24.f * x + 1.f));
        const float t2 = __builtin_floorf(__builtin_sqrtf(4.f * t1 + 5.f));
        uint32_t ctr = (t2 + 3.f)/ 2.f - 3;
        return  n - ctr - k;
    }


    // will never happen
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You should look up how to compute a [binomial coefficient using dynamic programming](#https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binomial-coefficient-dp-9/), as your current method will probably fail due to overflow/division rounding issues. From there, you can find the optimal `n` using binary search, unless there's a closed form solution for `n`.

Comment: Thank You  @wLui155, but there is no rounding error in my code. The division is always an integer division and produces no remainder (otherwise the definition of `n` over `k` = `\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}` wouldnt make sense). And I know that one is able to compute the binomial coefficient wie dynamic programming. This is what I'm right know doing, except for saving the intermediate results. And saving them is, as I said, not practical due do the already huge memory consumption of the rest of the application.
And there is no overlfow issue, because log2(1000 over 3) = 28, which fits perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If k is really limited to just 1, 2 or 3, you can use different methods depending on k:

- k == 1: `C(n, 1) = n` <= x, so the answer is `n`.
- k == 2: `C(n, 2) = n * (n - 1) / 4` <= x. You can solve the equation `n * (n - 1) / 4 = x`, the positive solution is `n = 1/2 (sqrt(16x + 1) + 1)`, the answer to the initial question should be `floor( 1/2 (sqrt(16x + 1) + 1) )`.
- k == 3: `C(n, 3) = n(n-1)(n-2)/6` <= x. There is no nice solution, but the formula for the number of combinations is straightforward, so you can use a binary search to find the answer.